# computation of the gram matrix for natural energy descent

Tags: riemannian-geometry, gradient-descent

I h*ave found a paper on https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.13163 where a modification of the natural gradient descent is proposed.
The natural gradient can be computet with (eq. 8)
$$
\nabla^EL(\theta) := G^{-1}_E(\theta)\nabla L(\theta).
$$
$\theta$ are the parameters of a neural network and L is the loss-function.
The formula for the "energy Gram matrix" is (eq. 6)*
$$
G_E(\theta)_{ij} := D^2E(u_\theta)(\partial_{\theta_i}u_\theta.\partial_{\theta_j}u_\theta)
$$
If I understood the paper right $D^2$ is the vector of soft derivatives up to the order 2 and $D^2E(u_\theta)$ is an operator
E(u) is the energy function. And in one example it is defines as (eq 16):
$$E(u):=\frac{1}{2} \int_{\Omega}\left|u^{\prime}\right|^{2} \mathrm{~d} x+\frac{1}{4} \int_{\Omega} u^{4} \mathrm{~d} x-\int_{\Omega} f u \mathrm{~d} x$$
The given "energy Gram matrix is (one equation after eq. 17)
$$D^{2} E(u)(v, w)=\int_{\Omega} v^{\prime} w^{\prime} \mathrm{d} x+3 \int_{\Omega} u^{2} v w \mathrm{~d} x$$

I dont understand how eq. 6 is used to derive the last equation. Thank you for your time